# 'unicode' object has no attribute 'replace'

Tags: python, django, unicode, replace

I have been running a Django site for a couple of months now and an hour ago began receiving the following error message (about three times a minute on various pages):

> AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'replace'

This is happening throughout the codebase, including in Django code itself. The codebase has not changed at all for a week and has been accessed frequently during that period and the error has *never* appeared. As it stands now I am getting several every minute - but somewhat coincidentally have not received any for the past ten minutes.

The error also appears to be reasonably sporadic in nature in that pages that error out with 500 can still load after a refresh or two.

Does anyone know what the cause of it may be? My server has WHM/CPanel installed but I don't think it should be touching the Python installation which I performed separately, so how this error has come up out of the blue has me quite baffled.

Comment: Something bad is going on there.  Check the integrity of your Python and Django installations.  Did you restart all web server instances?

Comment: Yeah, this is really bad. If standard methods on built-in objects are going missing you've got something messed-up on a basic level. What server/gateway software are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a long shot:

```
class unicode(object):
    pass

test = unicode()
test.replace()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Are there fake unicode objects somewhere?  (Like I said, a long shot.)  If you find the line of code where it's happening, put a try/except around it, print/log a repr of the object causing the problem, then reraise the error.